# Django query datetime for objects on hourly basis

Tags: django

I want to search the objects that are modified in a particular hour from datetime field. Example may be to extract object whose datetime field is for example 1st hour, 3rd hour, etc. of a particular date. Django filters provide to query on basis of year, month or day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
now=datetime.now()
Model.objects.filter(field__lte=now+datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

u may use not only **days**, but also minutes, seconds, hours ...

Comment: I have got the Idea what you said. The trick is to use timedelta and __lte, then it will work. Thanks

Comment: It worked like this <!-- thishour=14 Model.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetimeFrom+datetime.timedelta(hours=thishour),timestamp__lt=datetimeFrom + datetime.timedelta(hours=thishour+1)) -->

Comment: sorry for above as I don't know how to make seperate block for code, can any one help me in that.